# android onClick events and pro guard

Tags: android, xml, callback, proguard

i'm trying to obfuscate my app before uploading to the market.
i've setup pro guard and i allready handled the Serialzie issue ([prog guard maul - serialize](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html)) however i still have a problem (MethodNotFoundException) when trying to press one of the buttons in my home screen.
they are simple LinearLayout with background that in the xml have the android:onClick="doOnClick" attribute. in my HomeScreenActivity i have a method named :

`public void doOnClick(View v){...}`

that should be called whenever a button is pressed.
the code works **GREAT** when not obfuscated, but once obfuscated android class loader in unable to find my method. Before i move in to use only code and not xml callbacks (maybe advisable) i would like to know if there is a nice way around it.
Trying to prevent method obfuscation did not work for me (trying to prevent obfuscation of methods that extends Activity and are of the form public void *on*(android.view.View); or public void *On*(android.view.View).

If anyone have done it i'll appreciate the hint :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the -keep or keepclasswithmemebers do not apply since i already have `-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity` which will include ALL Activities.

I managed to find the problem in which the methods had been totally removed by proguard optimization and replaced with direct inline code. This happens because there are no specific calls to those functions in code; note that the XML calls to the code aren't taken into account.

adding the following to the proguard configuration solves the problem:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *On*Click(android.view.View);
   public void *on*Click(android.view.View);
}
```

Comment: Spelling: andriod.app.Activity => android.app.Activity

Comment: 10x :-) i would have never seen it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, this should work.

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class MyActivity {
   public void doOnClick(android.view.View);
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to keep the whole class, i have too many of them, what's the point obfuscating if most classes are out of the obfuscation ? :-)
also -keepmember did not work for me, i need more generic rule since not all my method are named doOnClick since i might have some of them for example (doOnFilter, doOnSort etc...) so again the rule doOn* did not do the trick.

Comment: You can also use public void *(android.view.View);

Comment: that includes too many methods, i thik... but i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your proguards file.

```
-keep class com.android.toto.ClassName {
    public void doOnClick(android.view.View);
}
```